# Mysql - Like & Regexp usage together

Tags: mysql, regex

I am optimizing my query since full text search returns irrevelant result when there is numbers and repetitive keywords in text.

What I want to do is to extract numbers on text and add X amount of point to relevance when sorting the result.

Everything works smoothly besides one thing;

When I want to extract and prioritize result with number Z, it also counts other numbers that includes number Z in any part of it.

For Example;

```
Sample Data
###############
Text 55.A
Text 55_B
Text #55ABC
Text 551234.
Text 55677#
Text 556

    Query
###############
... CASE WHEN (myTable.title like "% 55%") THEN ...

Expected output
###############
Text 55.A
Text 55_B

Actual output
###############
Text 55.A
Text 55_B
Text #55ABC
Text 551234.
Text 55677#
Text 556
```

How could I use REGEXP with LIKE, there can be symbols and characters after number I have given.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `REGEXP '([[:<:]]|_)55([[:>:]]|_)'`, or -  if it is MySQL 8.x+ - `REGEXP '(\\b|_)55(\\b|_)'`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much, this even deals with spaces which was problem for some cases to me. It works just as intended. I was thinking to use Like and Regex together thanks to my "junior" skills.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
REGEXP '([[:<:]]|_)55([[:>:]]|_)'
```

If you are using MySQL 8.x and newer that use ICU regex library use

```
REGEXP '(\\b|_)55(\\b|_)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MwAx1v/1)

The `(\\b|_)` matches a word boundary or a `_`, the `([[:<:]]|_)` matches a starting word boundary  or `_` and `([[:>:]]|_)`  matches a trailing word boundary  or `_`.